# Speeding up int list to binary conversion in python

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, type-conversion

Python beginner here. I have a large set of data that started of as a string of 16 bit ints, "1,2,3,4,5" and eventually need to turn into a byte aligned binary file.

Currently I have it working with the following:

```
#helper function
def unintlist2hex(list_input):
    for current in range(len(list_input)):
        list_input[current] = "%04X"%(int(list_input[current]))
return list_input

#where helper gets called in main code
for rows in dataset:
    row_list = rows.text.split(",")
    f_out.write(binascii.unhexlify("".join(unintlist2hex(row_list))))
```

but this runs quite slow up for my limited data test size(about 300,000 ints). How could I go about speeding it up? I profiled the code and most of the all the cycles are spent in `unintlist2hex()`

Note that I struggled to use `hex()`, and `bin()` because they had a tendency to truncate leading zeros.

Comment: I don't think you understand how data works. You are creating strings with the *characters* for "0" and "1" in them. That is **not** the same thing as setting 0 and 1 *bits* in a *byte*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm trying to really reflect on what you are saying here and missing your point. Isn't setting a 0x0 equivalent to creating a 0000 byte? Is your comment directed to "%04X" hex conversion?

Answer (score 1):

The `struct` module is probably best for this

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack("5I", *(int(x) for x in "1,2,3,4,5".split(",")))
'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00'
```

You can use `>` or `<` to set the endianess

```
>>> struct.pack(">5I", *(int(x) for x in "1,2,3,4,5".split(",")))
'\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05'
```

eg:

```
for rows in dataset:
    row_list = [int(x) for x in rows.text.split(",")]
    f_out.write(struct.pack("{}I".format(len(row_list)), *row_list))
```

Comment: Thanks! Ran the code and got about 2x factor, so that's pretty interesting. 
edit for prosperity sake:

    row_list = [int(x) for x in rows.text.split(",")]

Comment: Ah, yes should be a list comprehension of course :)